# How can i render openai gym in windows python3(cartpole)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

The programs I use are colab, vscode, vscode-jupyter, kaggle, pycharm. Pyton version 3.10.7
I tried to render the cartpole environment in every program I use. I tried many different gym package versions. But I can't. I wonder which python version, which gym version, or what are the things I should use in general. (IDE vs..)

Speaking for vscode, this is the code I ran and the output I got.
(PACKETS => pygame=2.1.0, gym=0.26.1, gym-notices=0.0.8, python=3.10.7)
[VSCODE code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDKae.png)

my code is working but what i want is to see this.I can't see that.
[i want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN1Ho.png)

PyCharm is the same and Spyder is the same.

GOOGLE COLAB I am running the same code again.This is the output[colab output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFvIN.png)

Comment: You need to be clear on what exaclty the problem is, what happens? do you get error messages? Be very detailed.

Comment: okey I updated with the photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code it will be **train and save** the model in specific folder in code.**(can run in Google Colab too)**

```
import gym 
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
import os

environment_name = "CartPole-v0"
env = gym.make(environment_name)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose = 1)

model.learn(total_timesteps=5000) #learn 
ppo_path = os.path.join('Cartpole_model')
model.save(ppo_path)
```

after it Check the result by loading the saved model **(To render Download saved model if you are in Google Colab, you have to run this in your own pc )**

```
environment_name = "CartPole-v0" #Env
env = gym.make(environment_name,render_mode="human")

ppo_path = os.path.join('Cartpole_model')
model = PPO.load(ppo_path, env) #load model    

obs = env.reset()
while True:
    action, _states = model.predict(obs)
    obs, rewards,  dones, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
env.close()
```

*(rendered output wont work in google colab, if you somehow linked vs code with google colab it wont output render but can train model !)*

Answer (score 2):

I think you are running "CartPole-v0" for updated gym library. This practice is deprecated.

Update gym and use CartPole-v1!

Run the following commands if you are unsure about gym version.

1. **pip uninstall gym**
2. **pip install gym**

This code will run on the latest gym (Feb-2023),

```
import gym
from tqdm import tqdm

n=500

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1", render_mode="human")
env.action_space.seed(82)

observation, info = env.reset(seed=82)

for _ in tqdm(range(n)):
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation,reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
    print("info : ",info);
    
    if terminated or truncated:
        observation, info = env.reset()
        
env.close()
```